# Как в админ. панели ModX вывести простейший CRUD по своей таблице MySQL?

Tags: mysql, modx

Читал про создание приложения ModX и тд. Создается полноценное приложение. Решил пока что не залезать в дебри...
По сути нужно вывести в **админ-панели** строки из своей таблицы (строка - это id + текстовое поле + числовое поле) и напротив одна галочка - удалить. Или две галочки - удалить и редактировать одно-единственное текстовое поле.
Как можно обойтись минимальными трудозатратами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тебе нужно не просто "вывести" - а еще и организовать возможность удаления - то тебе в любом случае надо идти в гугл и читать про создание своего компонента для модикса. Вот хорошая ссылка на целый курс где всё описано со всеми возможными моментами: https://bezumkin.ru/training/course1/

Comment: Безумкина почитываю иногда. а если как программа-минимум - просто вывести онли вью так сказать?

Comment: Если просто вывести, то можно по инструкции создать страничку - https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/custom-manager-pages/custom-manager-pages-in-2.3

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, поменяв тактику (админка лесом, все делаем на фронте):

1. Установил Login
2. На страничке поместил вызов формы Login и вызов сниппета, который выводит инфо из БД.
3. В сниппет добавил условие на проверку авторизованности юзера:

   ```
   if ($modx->user->isAuthenticated()) { echo 'ok блаблабла'; }
   ```
4. Теперь для неавторизованного юзера выводится только форма, для авторизовавшегося на фронтпанели - все печеньки из сниппета.

В плане безопасности считаю, что уровень не понижен, так как все увязано сугубо с проверкой пароля, пользователь будет один-единственный, поэтому такой тактики хватит за глаза. Тем более что требуемая логика действий юзера будет полностью покрыта и НЕ ПЕРЕКРЫТА миллиардом функции, которые есть в админ-панели, то есть иначе говоря, там ему делать нечего)))

**Покритикуйте!))**